# Understanding homomorphism from coalgebra to algebra

Tags: hopf-algebras

Could someone please explain what exactly a homomorphism from coalgebra to algebra (from this paper: [1](http://www.math.ups.edu/~bryans/Current/Spring_2014/3_Becca_HopfAlgebraFinal.pdf), page 10, definition 5.1). I understand a homomorphism as a map between two structures which preserves operations and their neutral elements, but which operations would it preserve between coalgebra and algebra? Thank you.

Comment: Usually this is done if the domain and range are bialgebras, so they have both a product and a coproduct.

Comment: Maybe linear map from coalgebra to algebra makes more sense, but I still don't understand how it can be defined. Found it there: http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~whitty/LSBU/MathsStudyGroup/SeligHopf.pdf , on page 5, section 4 (in the beginning).

Comment: Well it defines it explicitly with a formula. And it's exactly as I said: it's a map between bialgebras (specifically here a bialgebra with itself). In terms of linear maps, you can define a nontrivial linear map between any two nontrivial vector spaces over the same field. It's not a homomorphism, it's just a composition of particular important functions here, including the product and the coproduct.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. So a linear map from coalgebra ($A$, $\mu$, $\nu$) to algebra ($A$, $\Delta$, $\epsilon$) is just a linear map $A\to A$?

Comment: Yes it is. Comment too short.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an answer is not needed anymore, because the OP question has already been solved, but I think a clarification is needed for those who are not familiar with the subject.

If we have two vector spaces $V,W$ over a field $\Bbbk$ then we can consider the set $\mathsf{Hom}_{\Bbbk}(V,W)$ of all $\Bbbk$-linear maps from $V$ to $W$.

In the particular case in which $V$ has additionally a $\Bbbk$-coalgebra structure $(V,\Delta,\varepsilon)$ and $W$ has an algebra structure $(W,m,u)$, then $\mathsf{Hom}_{\Bbbk}(V,W)$ can be endowed with a product $*$ (called the *convolution product*) and a unit element $1$ that makes of it a monoid, namely
$$f*g:=m\circ (f\otimes g)\circ \Delta \qquad \text{and} \qquad 1:=u\circ\varepsilon,$$
which are still $\Bbbk$-linear maps from $V$ to $W$.

If $V=W=(B,m,u,\Delta,\varepsilon)$ bialgebra, then $\mathsf{Hom}_{\Bbbk}(B,B)=\mathsf{End}_{\Bbbk}(B)$ is a monoid as above and an inverse of the identity $\mathsf{Id}_B$ with respect to the convolution product (when it exists) is called and *antipode*. A bialgebra with an antipode is nowadays called a *Hopf algebra*.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Ender's answer about the convolution algebra, let me mention that among all linear maps between (differential graded) coalgebra and algebra, there are *twisting morphisms*, the ones who satisfy the Maurer-Cartan equation
$$ \partial(f) + f * f = 0  \ , $$
which are the heart of homotopical algebra and deformation theory, see for instance the Chapter 2 of Loday--Vallette [Algebraic Operads](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-30362-3) or Dotsenko--Shadrin--Vallette [Twisting procedure](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.11323.pdf) (to appear soon!).